# Why does a stepup transformer increases voltage but reduces current?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage

I know its a really basic question knowing the fact that you could just plug in the Voltage and Current into the proportionality formula. The thing is that I want a 'scientific/logical' explanation rather than the Maths.

And why don't a step-up transformer increases the current instead of the voltage?

Answer (score 1):

if a step-up transformer could increase both current and voltage, it would be making free energy out of nothing. So... without maths... because a transformer conserves energy, if the voltage gets stepped up, the current gets stepped down.

Here is another way to think of this: an electrical transformer is just like the gearbox in your car. Voltage = torque and current = RPM. In first gear, the input shaft turns four times and the output shaft turns once, so the RPM is divided by four while the input torque is multiplied by four times at the output shaft. This is just like a step-up transformer, in which the input current is divided by four and the input voltage is multiplied by four.

Comment: Why does more windings in the secondary ouput causes a rise in voltage rather than current?